# Clone and modify XmlHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototypal-inheritance

This maybe be seems like a total misunderstanding of a javascript way, but nevertheless here is an interest question: 
how to copy a XmlHttpRequest and make copy's send function include custom headers in a way that it will leave original XmlHttpRequest untouched.

Here is my (unsuccessful) attempt:

```
  Ajax.prototype._newReq = function() {
    var request = Object.create(XMLHttpRequest.prototype),
        token   = this.token;

    request._send = request.send;

    request.send = function(data) {
      request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
      if (typeof token !== 'undefined') {
        request.setRequestHeader("X-AUTH-TOKEN", token);
      }
      this._send(data)
    }

    return request;
  }
```

this code throws TypeError: Illegal invocation

Comment: So, you're goal is to have function that returns an XMLHttpRequest that already has one or two headers already set. Why not just get a new xhr each time? For example, http://jsfiddle.net/zLx8orx5/

Comment: sure, it's totally possible and maybe is the THE way. The question above on almost 95% consists from curiosity.

Comment: I think you really shoul use `new XMLHttpRequest()`. `Object.create` will not construct an instance, and might not work.

Answer (score 0):

the error was in the  request.setRequestHeader("X-AUTH-TOKEN", token); after I changed it to  this.setRequestHeader("X-AUTH-TOKEN", token); there were some kind of weird error and I did Kevin suggested.

Answer (score 0):

in if `(typeof token !== 'undefined')`  **!==** is not useful because **typeof always returns a string**, so use **!=**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).